# Java - Spring - put entries in map based on some condition

Tags: java, spring

In a Java app which uses Spring (Spring version 3.2.3),
I have something like this:

```
<bean id="pm" class="com.test.PropertyManager">
    <property name="targets">
        <map>
            <entry key="key01" value-ref="obj01" />
            <entry key="key02" value-ref="obj02" />
            <entry key="key03" value-ref="obj03" />
            <entry key="key04" value-ref="obj04" />
            <entry key="key05" value-ref="obj05" />
            <entry key="key06" value-ref="obj06" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is there any way to tell Spring to not put all entries in this map
but only some of them based on some property whose value can be
different for different environments the app is built for, and running in.

I mean, I am looking for something like:

```
<bean id="pm" class="com.test.PropertyManager">
    <property name="targets">
        <map>
            <entry key="key01" value-ref="obj01" if="${env1}"/>
            <entry key="key02" value-ref="obj02" if="${env1}"/>
            <entry key="key03" value-ref="obj03" unless="${env1}"/>
            <entry key="key04" value-ref="obj04" unless="${env1}"/>
            <entry key="key05" value-ref="obj05" />
            <entry key="key06" value-ref="obj06" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So e.g. I want two entries to be added when the app is in environment `env1`, two other entries to be added when the app is running in another `env2`, and yet two others to be always added.

Is that possible and if not, what are my alternatives?

Comment: Maybe profiles can help you.

Comment: you can easily do it with-in java config (and you can still combine XML and java config)

Answer (score 2):

There are different options:

1. If you need a different bean configuration per environment you could use profiles:

```xml
<beans profile="dev">
        <bean id="pm" class="com.test.PropertyManager">
            <property name="targets">
              ...
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
    <beans profile="production">
        <bean id="pm" class="com.test.PropertyManager">
            <property name="targets">
          ...
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

More on XML profiles: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-xml

2. If you need more flexibility use a factory (with Java config, that's straightforward):

```java
    public class PropertyManagerFactory {   
        public static PropertyManager getInstance() { 
            // Your initialization code (check env vars to build the map...)
        }
    }
```

Bean definition (notice the `factory-method`):

```
<bean id="propertyManager" class="com.test.PropertyManagerFactory" factory-method="getInstance" />
```

Usage (what's returned by the getInstance method will be injected here):

```
<bean id="accountService" class="com.test.AccountServiceImpl">
   <property name="propertyManager" ref="propertyManager"/>
</bean>
```

More info on using factory methods: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method

Comment: Thanks ... But both approaches seem inflexible and messy. 1st one - boilerplate stuff, repetition; 2nd one - do it yourself approach (where do I put that accountService btw?! and what am I supposed to do in getInstance?!). Well, I mean, if I am to do it myself, I can invent 100 ways to do it in a custom fashion. I was asking for a clean, Spring idiomatic way. Do you use profiles in your 2nd approach? I don't see that.

Comment: I think I don't want `<beans profile="dev">` I have > 100 beans which do not change based on the profile, just 2-3 beans which do change.

Comment: Also, please provide more details (pay no attention to my rating), I am not a Spring expert, far from that actually.

Comment: When using profiles in XML you can wrap only the bean that changes, not the whole config. A factory gives you more flexibility, I can't tell you how your initialization code looks like, that's up to you (check sys env...).

Comment: Well, I don't get much of what you're saying. NVM, will look for some good reads on the web related to that. If you can provide me with some references that would be great too.

Comment: Updated with more details and resources

Comment: Great, thanks a lot... Will check this out and try it all these days.